# I want a sandboxed test environment that is *always* an exact copy of Production

Tags: testing, clone, uat

I'm having an issue with a web application I am responsible for maintaining.

The system experiences regular bugs, and our support vendors are always asking us to see if we can "replicate the error in UAT". This is obviously a reasonable request. A lot of the time, for various reasons (some of which are clear, some of which are not), these errors are *not* present in UAT. This lack of bug reproducability in a testing environment is adding huge amounts of friction to the bug resolution process.

There are 3 key pieces of our system architecture where these bugs are flaring (the CMS, the API layer, and the database). I am proposing we set up a system job that *perpetually clones* these 3 parts of the system in to a sandboxed test environment. This cloning would happen periodically (eg, once every 24 hours), and automatically.

Is there a technical term for this sort of environment? Is this an established method of helping diagnose system issues? Is there somewhere I can read up on the industry best practices for establishing something like this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technical term for this kind of process is **replication** it is often done for some systems like databases, but normally not for testing purpose, but in order to increase available, so the replication is used as a failover spare.

An exact copy of a production system, with all the data is not you'll find often, due to the high demand on resources. Also at some points to two systems have to differ. Most systems (I know of) have tons of interfaces you just can't copy a complete system systems.

Also: you only need the copy of the production system when you actually debugging an issue. And if you are in the middle of that you probably don't want everything to go away and get replaced by a new copy.

So instead I would recommend to setup scripts that allows to obtain a copy of the relevant parts on demand.

Also you might want to consider how you might be able to modify your system to make it easier to setup a copy.

For example, when you have all the setup automated (with chef/docker or similar) you should be able to setup the same system again anywhere you want, so you now you just have to get the production data over.

Which is an interesting point. Production data often contains secret information (because it is vital to the business, or because it is personal data). You don't want this kind of stuff hang around in a test system everybody can access.